# Questions of 'Designing for Performance' document at Android Developer site

Tags: android, performance, documentation

In the **Avoid Creating Objects** section of the page [Designing for Performance](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html) in the Android Developer documentation I read some paragraphs for which I am not able to visualize a code representation:

*An array of ints is a much better than an array of Integers, but this also generalizes to the fact that two parallel arrays of ints are also a lot more efficient than an array of (int,int) objects. The same goes for any combination of primitive types.*

- How would these 'parallel arrays of ints' look like? Would it be something like instead of having a method with a signature such as getData():int[][] returning

  ```
     [a][b]
     [c][d]
     [e][f]
  ```

  ... it would be better to have two methods, each returning one of the 'columns' of data? as in:
  getFirstDimensionData():int[]

  ```
     [a]
     [c]
     [e]
  ```

  and a second one getSecondDimensionData():int[]

  ```
     [b]
     [d]
     [f]
  ```
- What is an 'array of (int,int) objects? ... something like an array of objects of a-type-not-yet-defined that has two int member instances defining its state?

The immediate next paragraph:

*If you need to implement a container that stores tuples of (Foo,Bar) objects, try to remember that two parallel Foo[] and Bar[] arrays are generally much better than a single array of custom (Foo,Bar) objects.*

... makes me think that the author is making up some sort of notation. I guess my key question is: is the author of the page using this `(somethingX, somethingY)` notation to refer to an arbitrary class that 'wraps' the elements inside the parentheses?

Finally, is this a standard notation or just something the author of the page created by himself and omitted to explain?

Can anyone, please, shed some light? :)

Thanks in advance,

Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they're saying is that

```
class foo {
    int a;
    int b;
}

foo[] bar;
```

Is slower than

```
int[] foo;
```

With `foo[row*2]` being `a` and `foo[row*2+1]` being `b`.

The notation (foo, bar) is trying to symbolize a class that contains `foo` and `bar` (like `(a,b)` in my above example).

I don't believe it's a standard notation, but it wouldn't be the first time I've been proven wrong.

Comment: Nice. I guess that's one of the reasons the Software Architecture and Documentation books tell you that if you use something that is not standard, you should put a legend nearby your document. ;)

Comment: Yikes! I hit the enter key and sent my comment before I said THANK YOU! Well, Thank you for your lightning fast response :)

Comment: No problem! Glad to help! Btw - if you accept this answer, we'll both get rep points. Thanks!

Comment: Give me 4 more minutes. I tried it and I got this 'You can accept an answer in 4 minutes' box. :)

Comment: Ha, that's what I get for rushing you :P

Comment: LOL. Done. Like I said, Mike: Thank you very much. Out of curiosity, how the h*ck did you figure out an answer for my question in such a short time? It took me longer to put together the question than it took you to type in the answer+reply to these comments. :D

Comment: I've been writing some JNI code for a game, so I'm a little bit more familiar how Android handles arrays and objects internally than I want to. That gives me a pretty good idea of what is slow, and what they're trying to say there. Have fun getting your app fast :)

Answer (score 0):

The author of that document is using a sort of loose mathematical notation. (x, y, z) is the way tuples are represented in mathematics. (It also happens to be the case that Python uses this notation, and given that this document came out of Google there is a reasonably high chance that the authors are fluent in Python. Python didn't invent the notation, however.)

The approach EboMike mentions is probably equally efficient, but it's not exactly what that doc is talking about. The doc is talking about *parallel arrays*, which is an approach where you use *n* arrays in place of a single array of records/structs/tuples/objects that have *n* fields.

More concretely, it's saying that if you want "a container that stores tuples of (Foo,Bar) objects", like this:

```
class FooBar {
  Foo foo;
  Bar bar;
}
...
FooBar[] array = new FooBar[n];
```

you could instead use "two parallel Foo[] and Bar[] arrays", like this:

```
  Foo[] foos = new Foo[n];
  Bar[] bars = new Foo[n];
```

This means that wherever you would have said `array[x].foo` you'd now say `foos[x]`.

With parallel arrays the garbage collector only has to deal with 2 + 2 * n objects (2 arrays, n Foos and n Bars) rather than 1 + 3 * n objects (1 array, n FooBars, n Foos and n Bars). So the bigger n is, the more significant the difference.

The downside is that you can't easily pass around the Foo and Bar together and it potentially makes the intent of your code less clear.

Comment: Your response leads me to think that my guess was right: the notation uses the parentheses to represent a class (FooBar in you comment) and the elements inside are instance members defining its state (foo:Foo and bar:Bar in your comment). I wish there was some note in the document from the original author. Honestly, I'm sold into the two answers. Thanks for taking the time to reply. Best,